# Xampp databse for students subjects

Tags: html, database-design, xampp, database-connection

How do I link my HTML website to a xampp database that contains their subjects so that when students enter the site, they can be able to view past questions of different subjects according to the term and academic session?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think by asking Xampp Database, you are asking about connecting to mysql database.
Inorder to connect your HTML website to mysql database, you need to use some programming language like PHP or Java.

I suggest, place your html files in the apache server i.e into htdocs then using php script you may connect to your database.

You may refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php to connect using PHP

Comment: This was helpful. Much gratitude.

Comment: If so, could you please upvote the answer. It would be helpful reference for users facing similar issue. Thank you in advance